# prevent JavaScript to run ayschronous

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

as you see below

```
} else {
    liveInfo
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .html('در حال پخش : ' + current)
    .fadeIn(1500)
    .delay(7000);
    if (next != ''){
        liveInfo
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .html('بعدی : ' + next)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(5000)
    }
}
```

two part of my code run asynchronously and I can't see first part result.

Which that I can't see its result:

```
    liveInfo
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .html('در حال پخش : ' + current)
    .fadeIn(1500)
    .delay(7000);
```

now I want to avoid run `if` block asynchronously with mentioned part.

I can do it like this, but it force me to have more same code:

```
} else {
    if (next != ''){
        liveInfo
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .html('در حال پخش : ' + current)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(7000)
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .html('بعدی : ' + next)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(5000)
    } else {
        // this code is repeated!
        liveInfo
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .html('در حال پخش : ' + current)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(7000)
    }
}
```

what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a synchronous task -- like the `if` condition or `.html()` -- wait in-line, many animation functions offer callbacks you can use. And, for those that don't (like `.delay()`), you can add the task to the same `fx` queue by wrapping them in [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2):

```
liveInfo
.fadeOut(2000, function () {
    liveInfo.html('در حال پخش : ' + current);
})
.fadeIn(1500)
.delay(7000)
.queue(function (done) {
    if (next != ''){
        liveInfo
        .fadeOut(2000, function () {
            liveInfo.html('بعدی : ' + next);
        })
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(5000)
    } 
    done();
});
```

Comment: For any `animation`s (including `fadeIn/Out`), the callback parameter would be a better choice for `html()` than queuing an extra function.

Comment: @Bergi True. But, `.delay()` doesn't offer a callback like `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()`, which would be necessary in this case.

Comment: Yes, that's sad. I already wonder whether it should be counted as a bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
} else {
    liveInfo
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .html('در حال پخش : ' + current)
    .fadeIn(1500);
    if (next != ''){
        liveInfo
        .delay(7000) /* move the delay to the next animation */
        .fadeOut(2000)
        .html('بعدی : ' + next)
        .fadeIn(1500)
        .delay(5000)
    }
}
```

I think just moving the delay to the next animation should work for what you want.